# Dual booted Windows 8.1 and ubuntu. Deleted Ubuntu partition stuck with Gnu Grub version 2.02

Tags: grub2, windows

I know similar things have been asked before, but they either apply to grub 1 or I am just too ignorant in the subject matter to follow the answers. I can't get ubuntu, bootloader, or windows recovery to boot from a usb (which is how I ran and installed ubuntu in the first place.) I just need a working computer ASAP for an upcoming project and am lost can someone explain it like I'm 5?

Comment: Was Windows 8 pre-installed so UEFI boot, or did you install it in BIOS boot mode? If UEFI, you can just go into UEFI and in UEFI boot tab change back to Windows as first or default boot. If BIOS you need to reinstall Windows boot loader to MBR. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader and if UEFI you may want to houseclean Ubuntu UEFI entries: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Windows 8.1 I believe your issue is that you are using UEFI boot. Most iso's are written for BIOS/Legacy.

Try this:

1. Restart computer
2. While the computer is loading, spam F2 and a screen should display (usually grey)
3. Now, navigate to the Security section and switch 'Secure Boot' to Disabled
4. Next, navigate to the Advanced section and change Boot mode from UEFI to CSM/Legacy
5. Now press F10 to exit saving changes
6. While the computer is rebooting spam F12 and using the Arrow Keys navigate to the desired USB you wish to boot with

I hope your problem is resolved :)

Please Note: Depending on your manufacturer you may have to use different F keys

Source: [Boot with legacy BIOS](http://www.top-password.com/blog/set-windows-8-pc-to-boot-with-legacy-bios-mode-instead-of-uefi-mode/)